# Parse nested JSON in .NET with similar data

Tags: c#, .net, json, nested, json.net

I have an API that I am calling that returns back a set of JSON.  This one in particular is to return a set of Projects to me.  These projects can have multiple sub-projects.  The structure is the same for all of the sub-projects as it is the main projects.  I can't seem to find anything that shows me how to parse the JSON so that it gives me some sort of usable class in .NET so I can show it on my web page.

Here is the structure (condensed because the original is HUGE and renamed projects and numbers to make it easier to read):

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 70000,
        "name": "Project 70000",
        "children": [ 
            {
                "id": 71000,
                "name": "Project 71000",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 71100,
                        "name": "Project 71100",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 71110,
                                "name": "Project 71110",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 71111,
                                        "name": "Project 71111"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 71112,
                                        "name": "Project 71112"
                                    }
                                 ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 80000,
        "name": "Project 80000",
        "children": [
           {
               "id": 81000,
               "name": "Project 81000"
           }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

What I think I want my class to look like (I may be wrong here) is this:

```
public class data 
{
    public List<project> { get; set; }    
}
public class project 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<project> children { get; set; }
}
```

I am using JSON.NET but anything I've tried winds up not doing anything or leaves me with errors in which I cannot build the project.  I've used JSON.NET in the past when there was a defined structure, but this one is throwing me for a loop!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're very close.  The issue seems to be that there is no property name for the list in your `data` class.  I would name that property `data` (to match the property in the JSON), then rename the class to something meaningful that makes sense for what this data represents.  Here I'm using `ProjectTree` for an example.

```
public class ProjectTree
{
    public List<Project> data { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Project> children { get; set; }
}
```

Then, deserialize to your `ProjectTree` class like this, and it should work fine:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProjectTree>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5gmosp

Answer (score 1):

You could create a self relationship for example:

```
public class Data
{
    public List<Project> data { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Project> children { get; set; }
}

var _data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);
```